# Nginx redirect all my /api calls to https

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

hello i have this current nginx configuration working fine for me but i want to make sure all the calls to my API are via https. I lost already hours trying all the solutions posted here but seems like i always get in a redirect loop.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
     listen 443 ssl default_server;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name test.com;

    location / {
            root /var/www/html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ @express;

    }

    location  @express {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

         }
}
```

How can i make sure all calls to /api are only via https? API is served by Express. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Personally I would split http into a separate server block containing just a redirect, forcing the entire site to be served only over https.

Comment: thanks Matt but i still have a presentation website served at www.domain.com , i have a control panel that will be better to be served via https and then the api. I was thinking for the main domain is better to keep http.

Comment: You're better off with everything on HTTPS, if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a separate server blocks for HTTP and HTTPS.

Try this one for HTTP:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name test.com;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location /api {
      redirect 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    root /var/www/html;
}
```

It should redirect all calls to `/api` to htttps.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Do you mean `return 301 ...`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys i end up with this conf that pleases me as it will redirect to https the cpanel part and also the /api and the main domain could use http and https.

```
server {
    # SSL configuration
     listen 443 ssl default_server;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
            root /var/www/html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ @express;
    }

    location  @express {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
         }
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name example.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```